# Ignoring lines when loading rdf dump using TDBLoader in JENA

Tags: jena, freebase, mql

When we are loading the large freebase rdf dump using tdbloader, there may be errors in few lines that may be due to an incorrect encoding, or mismatch of ">" or even some other kinds of errors. TDBLoader in this case throws and error saying that there is some mistake in a particular line number and suddenly stops.

Is there any mechanism with which we could note down this line, and in the next trial using command line we could mention this line number to be ignored , for TDBLoader?

Comment: Abhishek - you asked the same on users@jena.apache.org and the message Paolo links to is a response to your email (29-Dec).  There is also the discussion on freebase-discuss, which includes people who produce the dump.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I think I should use a single channel for these questions. I will stick to the users@jena list then. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, have a look at this message from jena-users mailing list (kudos to Andy):
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201212.mbox/%3C50DF4B56.9090208%40apache.org%3E